# How to make a mutated copy of PySpark Row object?

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, rdd

`from pyspark.sql import Row`

A a Row object is immutable. It can be converted to Python dictionary then mutated then back to a Row object. Is there a way to make a mutable or mutated copy without this conversion to dictionary and back to row?

This is need in a function run  in mapPartitions.

Answer (score 3):

Both `row.asDict()` and `**dict` do not preserve the ordering of your fields. Note that in python 3.6+ this might change. see [PEP 468](https://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0468/)

Similar to what @hahmed said. This dynamically creates a mutated row BUT with the same schema as the row passed in.

```
from pyspark.sql import Row
from collections import OrderedDict

def copy(row, **kwargs):
    d = OrderedDict(zip(row.__fields__, row)) #note this is not recursive
    for key, value in kwargs.iteritems():
        d[key]=value
    MyRow = Row(row.__fields__)
    return MyRow(*d.values())
```

This is useful if you need to transform your dataframe as a RDD and then make it a DF again

eg.

```
df_schema = df.schema
rdd = df_schema.rdd.map(lambda row: copy(row, field=newvalue))
new_df = spark.createDataFrame(rdd, df_schema)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the dynamic solution for making a mutated copy I came up with:

```py
from pyspark.sql import Row

def copy(row, **kwargs):
    dict = {}
    for attr in list(row.__fields__):
        dict[attr] = row[attr]

    for key, value in kwargs.items():
        dict[key] = value 

    return Row(**dict)

row =  Row(name="foo", age=45)
print(row) #Row(age=45, name='foo')

new_row = copy(row, name="bar")
print(new_row) #Row(age=45, name='bar')
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your actual use case, one possibility would be simply create a new Row object from the existing one.

```py
from pyspark.sql import Row
R = Row('a', 'b', 'c')
r = R(1,2,3)
```

Let's say we want to change `a` to `3` for `r`, make a new Row object out of `r`:

```py
R(3, r.b, r.c)
# Row(a=3, b=2, c=3)
```

While `r` still is:

```py
r
# Row(a=1, b=2, c=3)
```